# Receiver not registered exception error?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, illegalargumentexception

In my developer console people keep reporting an error that I cannot reproduce on any phone I have. One person left a message saying he gets it when they try to open the settings screen of my battery service. As you can see from the error it says that the receiver is not registered.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service .BatteryService@4616d688:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.app.notifyme.BatteryService$BatteryNotifyReceiver@4616d9d0
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3900(ActivityThread.java:129)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2173)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:com..BatteryService$BatteryNotifyReceiver@4616d9d0
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:805)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:859)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
at com.app.notifyme.BatteryService.onDestroy(BatteryService.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3150)
```

I register is in my onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(batteryNotifyReceiver,filter);
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

Unregister in onDestroy and also with a preference listener

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(batteryNotifyReceiver);

}
```

and this is my receiver in the service

```
private final class BatteryNotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    boolean connected;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();

            updatePreferences(prefs);

        level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);



        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)){
            connected = true;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)){
            connected = false;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){

                if(level < lastLevel){
                    if(level > 40){
                        edit.putBoolean("first", false).commit();
                        edit.putBoolean("second", false).commit();
                        edit.putBoolean("third", false).commit();
                       edit.putBoolean("fourth",false).commit();                            
                        edit.putBoolean("fifth", false).commit();
                    }
                    if(level == 40){
                        if(!first){
                        notification(context,battColor,battBlink,battVib,battSound);

                        edit.putBoolean("first", true).commit();
                        }
                    }else if(level == 30){
                        if(!second){
                        notification(context,battColor,battBlink,battVib,battSound);

                        edit.putBoolean("second", true).commit();
                        }
                    }else if(level == 20){
                        if(!third){
                        notification(context,battColor,battBlink,battVib,battSound);

                        edit.putBoolean("third", true).commit();
                        }
                    }else if(level == 15){
                        if(!fourth){
                        notification(context,battColor,battBlink,battVib,battSound);

                        edit.putBoolean("fourth", true).commit();
                        }
                    }else if(level == 5){
                        if(!fifth){
                        notification(context,battColor,battBlink,battVib,battSound);

                        edit.putBoolean("fifth", true).commit();
                        }
                    }
                lastLevel = temp;
            }
        }           

        Intent i = new Intent(context,BatteryNotifyReceiver.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }       
}
```

any idea why they would be getting that error?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The root of your problem is located here:

```
 unregisterReceiver(batteryNotifyReceiver);
```

If the receiver was already unregistered (probably in the code that you didn't include in this post) or was not registered, then call to `unregisterReceiver` throws `IllegalArgumentException`. In your case you need to just put special try/catch for this exception and ignore it (assuming you can't or don't want to control number of times you call `unregisterReceiver` on the same recevier).

Comment: Is it possible for the Android platform itself to do this?  I had similar code to the above, but with no other code at all that would unregister the service, and I get the same exception.

Comment: I have the same problem @electrichead, I can't see where the receiver would be unregistered before onDestroy() unless Android is doing it for me somewhere....

Comment: @user1088166, try overriding the onStop() method for your activity. In there add a try catch(IllegalArgumentException e) and purposely unregister your broadcast - see if that helps (just noticed this is a 3 year old comment :))

Comment: In my case the culprit was lazy initialization - I skipped registering because object was not initialized, so it was initialized later and I forgot receiver registration.

Comment: @electrichead no, it doesn't do it for you, you just need to choose the correct method: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver()` or `context.unregisterReceiver()`

Answer (score 30):

Be careful, when you register by

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver()
```

you can't unregister by

```
 unregisterReceiver()
```

you must use

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver()
```

or app will crash, log as follow:

> 09-30 14:00:55.458 19064-19064/com.jialan.guangdian.view E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.jialan.guangdian.view, PID: 19064
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.player.PlayService@141ba331: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.player.PlayService$PlayStatusReceiver@19538584
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:2941)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1395)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.player.PlayService$PlayStatusReceiver@19538584
>                                                                                  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:769)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1794)
>                                                                                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:510)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.player.PlayService.onDestroy(PlayService.java:542)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:2924)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1395) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Comment: This is a real answer to this problem! Just don't forget if you registered a global or local receiver before

Comment: you are a concentrated genuis :D

Answer (score 22):

Use this code everywhere for unregisterReceiver:

```java
if (batteryNotifyReceiver != null) {
    unregisterReceiver(batteryNotifyReceiver);
    batteryNotifyReceiver = null;
}
```

Comment: Still happens to me. Better use try-catch.

Comment: Try catch statement is better

Comment: This is still happening, cus many listerner are excuting reload page in my case.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in other answers, the exception is being thrown because each call to `registerReceiver` is not being matched by exactly one call to `unregisterReceiver`.  Why not?

An `Activity` does not always have a matching `onDestroy` call for every `onCreate` call.  If the system runs out of memory, your app is evicted without calling `onDestroy`.

The correct place to put a `registerReceiver` call is in the `onResume` call, and `unregisterReceiver` in `onPause`. This pair of calls is always matched.  See the Activity lifecycle diagram for more details. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Your code would change to:

```
SharedPreferences mPref
IntentFilter mFilter;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
 }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(batteryNotifyReceiver,mFilter);
    mPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
     unregisterReceiver(batteryNotifyReceiver, mFilter);
     mPref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

Comment: But this would cause the overhead of registering and unregistering many more number of times. I am not sure of the amount of overhead, but there will be some for sure.

Comment: Are you really suggesting leaving an exception throwing invalid handler in place because it would cost some CPU cycles to remove it?

Comment: these lifecycle methods are not available everywhere

Answer (score 11):

### EDIT: This is the answer for inazaruk and electrichead... I had run into a similar issue to them and found out the following...

There is a long-standing bug for this problem here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191

Looks like it started around Android 2.1 and has been present in all of the Android 2.x releases since.  I'm not sure if it is still a problem in Android 3.x or 4.x though.

Anyway, this StackOverflow post explains how to workaround the problem correctly (it doesn't look relevant by the URL but I promise it is)

[Why does keyboard-slide crash my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019606/why-does-keyboard-slide-crash-my-app)

Answer (score 10):

I used a try - catch block to solve the issue temporarily.

```
// Unregister Observer - Stop monitoring the underlying data source.
        if (mDataSetChangeObserver != null) {
            // Sometimes the Fragment onDestroy() unregisters the observer before calling below code
            // See <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165070/receiver-not-registered-exception-error</a>
            try  {
                getContext().unregisterReceiver(mDataSetChangeObserver);
                mDataSetChangeObserver = null;
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // Check wether we are in debug mode
                if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG_MODE) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare receiver as null and then Put register and unregister methods in onResume() and onPause() of the activity respectively.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (receiver == null) {
        filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}      

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (receiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        receiver = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the UI component that registers the BR is destroyed, so is the BR. Therefore when the code gets to unregistering, the BR may have already been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who will come upon this problem and they tried all that was suggested and nothing still works, this is how I sorted my problem, instead of doing `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(...)`
I first created a local variable of type LocalBroadcastManager,

```
private LocalBroadcastManager lbman;
```

And used this variable to carry out the registering and unregistering on the broadcastreceiver, that is

```
lbman.registerReceiver(bReceiver);
```

and

```
lbman.unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your `broadcastReceiver` is defined like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // your code

    }
};
```

If you are using `LocalBroadcast` in an Activity, then this is how you'll unregister:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

If you are using `LocalBroadcast` in a Fragment, then this is how you'll unregister:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

If you are using normal broadcast in an Activity, then this is how you'll unregister:

```
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

If you are using normal broadcast in a Fragment, then this is how you'll unregister:

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unregister broadcast receiver in Try Catch

```
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.printf(e.getMessage());
    }
```