# Getting fatal exception during intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a simple app that watches the device's battery level.
I use this code:

```
private void setProperImageByBatteryLevel() {

    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
            int level = -1;
            if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
            }
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Charge: " + Integer.toString(level) + "%");
            }
            if (level > 80) {
                batteryImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat100);
            } else if (level > 60) {
                batteryImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat80);
            } else if (level > 40) {
                batteryImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat60);
            } else if (level > 20) {
                batteryImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat40);
            } else if (level > 0) {
                batteryImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat20);
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    activity.registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
}
```

It works properly, but sometimes i get the following exception: (about 10/1 times)

```
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000000 (has extras) } in hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2@4053e3b8
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2@4053e3b8
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:919)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2.onReceive(Battery.java:92)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
01-21 13:16:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(7810):     ... 9 more
```

Anybody see the problem?

E D I T :

I changed the way you told me now i got this:

```
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000000 (has extras) } in hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2@40534080
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2@40534080
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:919)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2.onReceive(Battery.java:93)
01-23 14:43:40.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
```

Comment: Do not register broadcast register inside itself. Either take it in manifest or in Activity your problem is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: hu.trendency.activitimap.widgets.Battery$2@4053e3b8

Comment: Can refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165070/receiver-not-registered-exception-error..

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
context.unregisterReceiver(this);
```

to

```
activity.unregisterReceiver(this);
```

Because the context that you get in `onReceive()` may or may not be the same context that you used to register the receiver in the first place.

You can also surround the call to `unregisterReceiver()` with a try/catch block and catch and ignore `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Another exception, maybe i should start it over.

Comment: Well, you need to keep track of where you are registering the receiver, so that you can unregister it appropriately. Either that, or just catch and ignore all exceptions when unregistering.

Comment: Based on your edit, it is throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` in `unregisterReceiver()`, but you obviously aren't catching that even though I suggested you do so. Please post your updated code.