# Receiver not registered error when onDestroy function called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When I create class that extends BrodcastReceiver and register it.
Error `Unable to destroy activity, Receiver not registered: null` onDestroy() function in MainActivity When call unregisterReceiver.

onCreate():

```
ConnectionChangeReceiver connectionChangeReceiver = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(connectionChangeReceiver, filter);
```

onDestroy():

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("YourActivity", "onDestroy");
    unregisterReceiver(connectionChangeReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

ConnectionChangeReceiver Class:

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "CONN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

manifest: `UPDATE:` After adding `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mamrezo.mapapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mamrezo.mapapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ConnectionChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165070/receiver-not-registered-exception-error). Do you unregister it somewhere else and is it possible you are unregistering again?
Are you pausing(and you have unregistering code in onPause()) and then starting again and you forgot to put the register in onResume()?

Comment: Are you sure the receiver is being registered? Do you have the correct `<uses-permmision>` setting in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Squonk <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: @mamrezo : Hmm, OK. Does the receiver work? In other words do you see the `Toast` when network changes occur?

Comment: @mamrezo : Edit your question to show the logcat data for when you get that error.

Comment: @mamrezo : Why have you added BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: @Squonk yes i know i add `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />` now it is working fine

Comment: wow I am person number 4 to have this issue..  I also seem to have in my code:  extends BroadcastReceiver.   what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I always `register` the receiver in the `onStart` and `unregister` it in the `onStop`. I knew this thanks to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24391706/1203797

If its still not working in your case, simply wrap`unregisterReceiver(connectionChangeReceiver);` a `try-catch` block would be the answer, as stated in the link i posted above.

Or you can register it in the `manifest`, example :

```
    <receiver android:name=".ConnectionChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: you can register it in the manifest: i do but still not working

Comment: i add register `onStart` and unregister `onStop ` but still not working

Comment: @mamrezo is there any error message when you register it in the `manifest`

Comment: @mamrezo sorry, just to make sure : you should remove the `java` code for `register` and `unregister` when you declare it in the manifest. Have you done that?

Comment: when i use `BroadcastReceiver` without Class works well but when i create class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` i have this error

Comment: @mamrezo There should be no problem..have you checked my previous comment?

Comment: when i declare it in the manifest and remove the unregister from onDestroy and onStop i have no error but The Class is not working

Comment: @mamrezo Please post your `manifest` code or try to use the `try-catch` (see my answer)