# Android O Preview 1 can't open Setting, "Setting has stop"

Tags: android, setting, android-8.0-oreo

I use the `Nexus 6P`, and system is `Android O Preview 1`.

I have been used the preview system for two month, and it's normal.

Today I want to update system, I find I can't open the system app `"Setting"`. it's will show that `'Setting has stop'`.

Then I watch the `Logcat` in `Android Studio`, has `Error` log below:

```
07-25 17:16:31.515 21875-21875/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.android.settings, PID: 21875
                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.CellularDataCondition$Receiver@1d9a5b0
                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1152)
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1422)
                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:639)
                                                   at com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.Condition.onSilenceChanged(Condition.java:115)
                                                   at com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.Condition.setActive(Condition.java:90)
                                                   at com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.CellularDataCondition.refreshState(CellularDataCondition.java:47)
                                                   at com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.ConditionManager.refreshAll(ConditionManager.java:77)
                                                   at com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.ConditionManager$ConditionLoader.onPostExecute(ConditionManager.java:266)
                                                   at com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.ConditionManager$ConditionLoader.onPostExecute(ConditionManager.java:261)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6535)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

07-25 17:16:31.519 789-2848/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings
```

I can't update now, and Setting can't open. What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165070/receiver-not-registered-exception-error

Comment: I know the Error unregisterReceiver, but it's system app, the "Setting", I can't edit its code. I don't know why it's  have error suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing factory reset?
Go to fastboot mode and use "fastboot -w"